# Match One or the other condition

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to do something like this :

- Flow must have a relationship with :

  - An Application **OR**
  - A Partner

My Flow must have one of these two relationships.
I tried to something like this :

```
    MATCH (c:Flow)-[y:AppliFlux]-(d:Application)
    OPTIONAL MATCH (c)-[r:FlowPart]-(e:Partner)
    return c
```

But it doesn't return what i need.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `WHERE` with conditions checking by the relationships existence:

```
MATCH (c:Flow)
WHERE (c)-[:AppliFlux]-(:Application)
OR (c)-[:FlowPart]-(:Partner)
RETURN c
```

**[EDIT]**

After some talk in the chat, the solution that best fits the requirements from the question is the following:

```
MATCH (a:Domain)-[r:AppliDom]-(b:Application)-[t:AppliFlux]-(c:Flo‌​w)-[y:AppliFlux]-(‌​d:‌​Application)-[u:Appl‌​iDom]-(e:Domain) 
RETURN {a:a,c:c,e:e} as elements 
UNION 
MATCH (c)-[r:FlowPart]-(e:Partner) 
RETURN {c:c} as elements
```

That is: the use of `UNION` returning projections.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But your solution doesn't work if i need to get the Partners or the Applications. My queries returns can change if needed.

Comment: Hello @Philigane. Have you tried using two `OPTIONAL MATCH`s? `OPTIONAL MATCH (c:Flow)-[y:AppliFlux]-(d:Application)
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)-[r:FlowPart]-(e:Partner)
return c`

Comment: Thanks for the reply again :). If i put 2 OPTIONAL MATCH i'll get some Flow(s) which haven't any of these relationships.

Comment: @Philigane and what about an `UNION`? `MATCH (c:Flow)-[y:AppliFlux]-(d:Application)
RETURN c
UNION 
MATCH (c)-[r:FlowPart]-(e:Partner)
RETURN c`

Comment: I don't really know what UNION do but when i'm trying the query i got an error : 

          `All sub queries in an UNION must have the same column names (line 3, column 1 (offset: 138))

          "UNION MATCH (c)-[r:FluxPart]-(e:Partenaire) "`

Comment: @Philigane can you post your complete query please?

Comment: Sure.
`MATCH (a:Domain)-[r:AppliDom]-(b:Application)-[t:AppliFlux]-(c:Flow)-[y:AppliFlux]-(d:Application)-[u:AppliDom]-(e:Domain)
RETURN a,c,e
UNION
MATCH (c)-[r:FlowPart]-(e:Partner) 
RETURN c`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162823/discussion-between-bruno-peres-and-philigane).

Comment: @Philigane please see the chat.